# How to store table data in cache memory in Node Express?

Tags: node.js, forms, caching, express, store

I want to store data into cache memory from one form and retrieve it to another page table, repeat this process again and again.

Comment: actually i have a web page there is a button after pressing it a pop up will open then it gets the value from pop up form then stores the values in main page table as first row then i have to repeat it again and again fill the form and add details to table as multiple row..
 i tried node-cache manager-express

https://github.com/BryanDonovan/node-cache-manager-express-example

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask reformat your question and you will be more likely to get the answer you are looking for

Answer (score -1):

[SQL lite](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/) is a great way to handle in-process data.

It can maintain a database in-memory or in a disk file and execute ordinary queries against it.

```
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
let db = new sqlite3.Database(':memory:');


let db = new sqlite3.Database(':memory:', (err) => {
  if (err) {
    return console.error(err.message);
  }
  console.log('Connected to the in-memory SQlite database.');
});
```